# Paste field content directly to node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

The content type article has a field called field_kategorie.
It should be output in the URL in the title of the node with.

node.html.twig doesn't work as expected.

```
<a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ field_kategorie }}{{ label }}</a>
```

How to do that?

Comment: It should be `{{ content.field_kategorie }}`

Comment: no, that doesn't work. field_kategorie is an taxonomy field. Is this important?

Comment: Is the field enabled under Manage Display on the content type?

Comment: Yes. Dump{{... returns only "dump" whiteout content.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ node.field_test.value }}` works in node.html.twig for "normal" fields, not for taxonomy fields.